# Visual studio uninstall setup trying to uninstall things that dont exsist

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, updates

help ? log: i301: Applying execute package: Windows81_x64, action: Uninstall, path: 2999226, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" /uninstall /kb:2999226 /quiet /norestart' this kb or wusa doesent exsist. thats my problem

Comment: C:\Windows\SysNative is really C:\Windows\System32

Comment: yeah i realised that but after couple of hours i got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. looks like i found a solution. first i went to install this kb2999226 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49071 (NOT WIN7 ONE) then just tried to uninstall from the command prompt /uninstall /force and then it worked.